# Will disabling and deleting iCloud photos also delete iCloud shared albums?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

My photos were taking up too much iCloud storage space, so I decided to "Disable and Delete" my iCloud photos. However, I also have quite a number of iCloud Shared Albums that I've shared with other users. Will selecting the "Disable and Delete" option only delete my own photos uploaded on iCloud, or will it also delete all my iCloud Shared Albums that I have shared with users?

I understand that iCloud Shared Albums don't count towards iCloud storage and iCloud Shared Albums is also activated under a different area in settings (Settings -> iCloud -> Turn on iCloud Photo Sharing). Is it right, then, to think that disabling and deleting iCloud photos (therefore clearing up my iCloud storage) will have no bearing on iCloud Shared Albums? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Shared photos don’t count against your storage, but they do depend on you having an iCloud primary library on one device.

We would need to know how you manage your photo library to give any more guidance. You could be iPhone only, iPad or Apple TV or Windows and Mac in the mix. Lots of variables and a call to Apple support is the best way for you to understand your exact setup if you have questions.

In a nutshell, you could delete all the photos from your online library to shrink it and leave just the shared photos to reduce your bill and toll on the free space Apple gives to each AppleID when they activate iCloud.